# How to join multiple columns as multiple columns?

Tags: mysql

I have a `trip` table with columns `from_city` and `to_city` which contain foreign key to `city` table.

How to join with a `city` table with `id` as primary key so that I get a result joined table with `from_city_name` and `to_city_name`?

Comment: Not sure what is the issue. Just join the `city` table twice using different aliases.

Answer (score 1):

Do an inner join twice, as illustrated below. For more information on SQL joins see [MySQL Join Made Easy For Beginners](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/)

```
SELECT
    B.name from_city_name, C.name to_city_name 
FROM 
    trip A 
INNER JOIN 
    city B
ON A.from_city=B.id 
INNER 
    JOIN city C 
ON A.to_city=C.id;
```